# How to get rid of the time in new Date () object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, date, typescript

I have the following `class` where I specify a `Date` type for the `birtDate`.

When I create an instance of the class, and I fill the date in the following way, this is what I get on the front-end: `Sun Jun 17 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

I only want the `Jun 17 2012`part, so what format should I provide in order to get that ?

The class:

```
export class Person {
    public firstname: String;
    public lastname: String;
    public birthDate: Date;
    public area: String;
    public rating: number[];
}
```

An instance of the class:

```
   {
      firstname: 'Elin',
      lastname: 'Skuladottir',
      birthDate: new Date(2012, 5, 17),
      area: 'Greater Copenhagen',
      rating: []
    }
```

Comment: save the birthDate as you wish, use date pipe to show it https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe. (personally, I think that the use of moment.js is in case you need "operate" with dates, if only you want to show it's not necesary.

Comment: NOTE: better birthDate:new Date('2012-05-17") than birthDate:new Date(2012,5,17) -you can have problems with GTM zones -

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleDateString` to format the `Date`.

try with this function:

```js
   
function formatDate(date) {
 var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
 return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options).replace(/,/g,'');
}

var person = {
  firstname: 'Elin',
  lastname: 'Skuladottir',
  birthDate: new Date(2012, 5, 17),
  area: 'Greater Copenhagen',
  rating: []
}
    
    
console.log(formatDate(person.birthDate));
```

Comment: I want to get rid of `Sun` as well. How to implement that as well ?

Comment: I have updated the code to get rid of `Sun`. Just remove `weekday` from the options object.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing beats Moment.js in operations related to Dates
>   Take a look at the [Moment.js docs](http://%3C!--%20begin%20snippet:%20js%20hide:%20false%20console:%20true%20babel:%20false%20--%3E%20%20%3C!--%20language:%20lang-js%20--%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20obj%20=%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20firstname:%20'Elin',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lastname:%20'Skuladottir',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20birthDate:%20new%20Date(2012,%205,%2017),%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20area:%20'Greater%20Copenhagen',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rating:%20[]%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20ddd:%20Sun%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20MMM:%20Jun%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20DD:%2017%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20YYYY:%202012%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(moment(obj.birthDate).format(%22ddd%20MMM%20DD%20YYYY%22));%20%20%3C!--%20language:%20lang-html%20--%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%3C!--%20end%20snippet%20--%3E) that makes the following code *tick*

```js
let obj = {
  firstname: 'Elin',
  lastname: 'Skuladottir',
  birthDate: new Date(2012, 5, 17),
  area: 'Greater Copenhagen',
  rating: []
};

// ddd: Sun
// MMM: Jun
// DD: 17
// YYYY: 2012
console.log(moment(obj.birthDate).format("ddd MMM DD YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> Don't forget to include the Moment.js cdn into your index.html